# how to erase text between tags

Tags: javascript, regex, tags

I'm getting some paragraphs from a web service, but depending of the source url, sometimes I get something like this:

**Example 1**: I ask for the text in this online news http://tn.com.ar/sociedad/paso-2017-te-afiliaron-de-prepo-contanos-tu-historia-en-tn-y-la-gente_806433 Then I get the content but the first paragraph I don't need it.

```
<p> text to erase </p> <--- First 
<p> more text </p>
<p> more text </p>
```

**Example 2**: I ask for the text in this online news http://www.lanacion.com.ar/2044592-ranking-las-15-mejores-propuestas-de-los-portenos-para-mejorar-la-ciudad Then I get the content but the last paragraph I don't need it.

```
<p> text </p>
<p> more text </p>
<p> text to erase </p> <--- Last
```

I know what paragraph I need to erase depending the url where I took the text.

I want to how can I erase it. I know that it can be done with a regex, but I don't know nothing about that.

Comment: Do you know before-hand the exact text that needs to be removed? How do you know which text needs to be removed?

Comment: @RichGoldMD Yes I know, because when I make the request asking for the text of url A then the first paragraph should be erase. When I ask for the text of url B then the last paragraph should be erase. Both url always behave like that.

Comment: Can't you make changes to the webservice not the return what's not required assuming you own and have access to the webservice.

Comment: Is there some set of rules you can apply to identify what needs to be removed? You can recognize it when you look at it, can you boil that down to something you can share?

Comment: @user8271644 no I can't because I don't own the web service.

Comment: @RichGoldMD I edit my first post.

Comment: Can you tell us how YOU know you don't need those paragraphs? What are the criteria?

Comment: @RichGoldMD because in example 1, the content of the first paragraph it has the caption of the image. In example 2 the content of last paragraph has the text of the comments . What I want is only the text of the article

Comment: Unfortunately we'd need to see the actual output from the webservice to identify any data in there that might be helpful.

Comment: Is the data enclosed in some kind of div. If not, you can enclose it in div and use javascript jquery to find the n child as in the example and remove the text. I am making a small jsfilddle for demo will post the code shortly. https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: @RichGoldMD Im using https://textracto.com which has a live demo. If you insert the links I put in my first post, you will see in "main content" what i say.

Comment: Made a code to remove the first p and the third p. I think need to add some logic to decide when to remove the first and when the third one. http://jsfiddle.net/8mto86an/1/. Hope this helps

Comment: @user8271644 thanks! will work with it!

Answer (score 0):

Erasing the text inside first paragraph:

```
document.querySelector('p:first-child').innerText = ""
```

Erasing the text inside the last paragraph:

```
document.querySelector('p:last-child').innerText = ""
```